# jQuery: Weird error: $("#dialog").jqm is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I get a really weird error which I couldn't localize/know from where it comes.
Firebug says:

> Error: $("#dialog").jqm is not a
> function Source:
>
> http://www.daniello.nstrefa.pl/scripts/jquery.init.js
>
> Line: 3

The file jquery.modal.js is loaded and even if I put the content of it inside the jquery.init.js I get the same error.
Could a expert take a look on it and write what's wrong?

Site:
http://www.daniello.nstrefa.pl/

Comment: Yes, it will be added the line before. Also if I add a `console.log($("#dialog"));` I get the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading jQuery twice (well, three times, actually). After `jQuery.init.js` added the plugin's extra functions to the `jQuery` object, jQuery is loaded again, replacing the old object with a new pluginless one.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is not related to the plugin but the previous error on the `checkForm()` function

```
//...
if (siw && siw.selectingSomething)
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you have a lot going on in this page. What appears to be happening is that the #dialog element is being created after the $("#dialog").jqm call. I think you should consider doing some refactoring. First off, make sure you only have one jquery.js referenced. I would also make sure that it is above your other jquery libraries (look for Steve Souders recommendations - google him) and at the bottom of your page (prior to /body). The function that creates the #dialog (whereever that is) should be doing it in a document.ready somewhere.